# Normalized ancular choice (NaCH) in sDNA

Tags: sdna

Based on previous experience with depthmap, I would like to inquire about a question: does sDNA has the equivalent value of NaCH (Normalized Angular Choice) or Total Depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to calculate a measure similar to NaCH

1. run sDNA with "outputsums" in advanced config, to produce sum of angular distance (SAD - like total depth in degrees) as well as the other measures
2. calculate field afterwards using angular betweenness (BtA) and SAD

The original paper for NACH is *Normalising least angle choice in Depthmap and how it opens up new perspectives on the global and local analysis of city space Bill Hillier, Tao Yang, Alasdair Turner. JOSS*

The formula in the appendix is

```
NACH = log(Choice+1)/log(TotalDepth+3)
```

(what the authors put in the main body of the text is wrong as they omit the brackets)

The +1 and +3 are arbitrary quantities added to ensure the range of NaCH is both real and finite. The +1 is not needed in sDNA as betweenness will never be zero in an unweighted analysis, still you can leave it in if you want to avoid negative NACH. SAD can be 0 so you need +2 on the denominator to avoid a potentially infinite result, but not +3.

So a similar measure with sDNA would be

```
NACH = log (betweenness) / log (SAD/90 + 2)
```

This is not identical to depthmap NACH but qualitatively will behave the same way. The +1, +3 used in the original paper are unrelated to the units of choice and total depth, so fundamentally it’s an arbitrary quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Normalised choice aims to solve the paradox that segregated designs add more total (and average) choice to the system than integrated ones.
The key issue, here, is space syntax segment mapping - the representation itself is creating the problem: complex non-linear links are transformed in multiple segment thus increasing "depth" i.e. segregated designs add more total (and average) choice to the system than integrated ones. As sDNA consider nonlinear link as one spatial unit however complex non-linear it is this phenomena does not happen with sDNA using the link (polyline) representation. Thus it then seems a bit strange to use NACH or NAIN with sDNA.